# Postgres: extracting multiple bit-columns from single 'flags' column after join with 2nd table

Tags: postgresql, optimization, temporary-tables, bitwise-comparison

I have a query similar to this below. As you can see, there are multiple parts which are very similar.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    aaaa, 
    bbbb,
    tags
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
        FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B 
            ON A.id = B.parent_id
        WHERE A.buzz=C.buzz
            AND B.tags & 1 <> 0
    ) as "has_children_tag_1"
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
        FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B 
            ON A.id = B.parent_id
        WHERE A.buzz=C.buzz
            AND B.tags & 2 <> 0
    ) as "has_children_tag_2"
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
        FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B 
            ON A.id = B.parent_id
        WHERE A.buzz=C.buzz
            AND B.tags & 4 <> 0
    ) as "has_children_tag_3"
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
        FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B 
            ON A.id = B.parent_id
        WHERE A.buzz=C.buzz
            AND B.tags & 8 <> 0
    ) as "has_children_tag_4"
FROM A
LEFT JOIN Z
    ON A.id = Z.id
```

I know one thing, that I cannot split `flag` column into multiple bit columns, so I have to figure out how to query my existing tables in efficient way.

I am wondering is it possible (I don't know how to do that) to create some kind of temporary table for part:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B 
        ON A.id = B.parent_id
    WHERE A.buzz=C.buzz
```

to have a possibility to run on this tmp table `WHERE B.tags & 1 <> 0`, `WHERE B.tags & 2 <> 0`, etc.

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a single mention of `flag` in your query.  Also, it would be nice to see (in English, not SQL ;) what you try to achieve.

Comment: Your example query is unclear, because of the `C.buzz` references: there is no `C` table in your query. Is the main `FROM A` supposed to be `FROM C` (and, accordingly, `ON A.id = Z.id`, `ON C.id = Z.id`)?

Comment: The usual suspects are also missing: Table definition and Postgres version. Please improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could merge the subqueries using this model:

```
SELECT bool_or(B.tags&1<>0) as "has_children_tag_1",
       bool_or(B.tags&2<>0) as "has_children_tag_2",
       bool_or(B.tags&4<>0) as "has_children_tag_3",
       bool_or(B.tags&8<>0) as "has_children_tag_4"
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.parent_id
WHERE [conditions]
```

`bool_or` is an aggregate function that evaluates to true if at least one value is true, so that should lead to the same results as the multiple `count(*)>0` in the question, except as one single subquery.

To push these columns into an otherwise unrelated query, you may add the above subquery as a CTE in a WITH clause, and just put it in the FROM list. For instance, modifying your original query:

```
WITH flags AS
(SELECT bool_or(B.tags&1<>0) as "has_children_tag_1",
       bool_or(B.tags&2<>0) as "has_children_tag_2",
       bool_or(B.tags&4<>0) as "has_children_tag_3",
       bool_or(B.tags&8<>0) as "has_children_tag_4"
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.parent_id
WHERE [conditions] )
SELECT 
  id, 
  aaaa, 
  bbbb,
  tags,
  has_children_tag_1,
  has_children_tag_2,
  has_children_tag_3,
  has_children_tag_4
FROM flags,A
LEFT JOIN Z
    ON A.id = Z.id
```